# Realm accessed from incorrect thread after download completed Swift 3

Tags: swift, realm, alamofire

I have an app and user can download pdf file. I recently move to alamofire 4 and swift 3. I try to view pdf file after download completed but it throw `Realm accessed from incorrect thread.`

here's my code:

```
Alamofire.download(url, method: .get, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, to: destination)
        .downloadProgress(queue: DispatchQueue.global(qos: .utility)) { progress in

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                magazineObject.progressBarDownload = self.percentProgress
                magazineObject.progressBarTitle = self.percentProgressNext.cleanValue

                }
            }
        }
        .validate { request, response, temporaryURL, destinationURL in
            self.localPath = destinationURL
            magazineObject.pathDatabase = String(describing: self.localPath!)
            magazineObject.progressBarDownload = Double(self.percentProgressFinal)
            magazineObject.progressBarTitle = Float(self.displayFinalLabelPercent).cleanValue
            magazineObject.statusDarkViewAfterRelaunch = 1
            magazineObject.statusDownload = self.statusDatabase

            try! realm.write {
                realm.add(magazineObject)
            }
            return .success
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try create another realm thread object inside the `validate` block

```
.validate { request, response, temporaryURL, destinationURL in
    self.localPath = destinationURL
    magazineObject.pathDatabase = String(describing: self.localPath!)
    magazineObject.progressBarDownload = Double(self.percentProgressFinal)
    magazineObject.progressBarTitle = Float(self.displayFinalLabelPercent).cleanValue
    magazineObject.statusDarkViewAfterRelaunch = 1
    magazineObject.statusDownload = self.statusDatabase

   // create new object here 
   let realm = try! Realm()

    try! realm.write {
        realm.add(magazineObject)
    }
    return .success
}
```

You can check details at realm docs https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#using-a-realm-across-threads